# Rails index view - show column data as separate header row before groups of records

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am stuck in a problem where I have to show column td data as a seperate header row before records. Here is the code on which I have to perform this operation:

Rails index.html.erb code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Product</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Role</th>
  <th>Kind</th>
  <th>State</th>
  <th>Template</th>
  <th>AMI ID</th>
  <th>Last update</th>
  <th></th>
</tr>

<% @cb_templates.each do |cb_template| %>

<tr>
<th><%= cb_template.product ? cb_template.product.name : '' %></th>
<td><%= cb_template.title %></td>
<td><%= cb_template.role %></td>
<td><%= @kind_options[cb_template.kind][0] %></td>
<td><%= @state_options[cb_template.state][0] %></td>
<td><%= cb_template.template_id %></td>
<td><%= link_to cb_template.ami_id, @vdi_view_image_uri + cb_template.ami_id %></td>
<td><%= cb_template.updated_at.strftime("%b %d, %H:%M") %></td>
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <%= link_to "Show", product %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(cb_template)%>
</td>
</tr>
< % end %>
</table>
```

ISSUE: product name take too much space on :index pages  and prevents information on the right from showing when product name is too long.

TASK: elaborate layout of above :index pages, so product name is not shown on the left for each record, but shown as separate header row before groups of records. Implement this by adding a helper method in app/helpers/application_helper.rb and using it on :index pages.

I tries a lot to create table header but got no success, let me know if any one has any idea  on how to perform this task..

Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

Use `group` to group by product and then first loop over the groups to render `<th colspan="8">PRORUCT</td>` and within loop over the other attributes:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group

A helper is not needed for this at all. Please try to implement this yourself. It's not too difficult and you will certainly learn something by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks okay to me; I suppose the main issue is:

> ISSUE product name take too much space on :index pages and prevents
>   information on the right from showing when product name is too long

This is either going to be a CSS problem or resolved with  [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate):

---

**CSS**

This will prevent the `<th>` elements having multi-line text, and having text that's too long. It uses the [`text-overflow` property](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
table
  tr
    th
      width: 150px
      overflow: hidden
      text:
          overflow: ellipsis
      white:
          space: no-wrap
```

---

**Truncate**

Alternatively, you can use [`truncate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) to truncate the text:

```
<%= cb_template.product ? truncate(cb_template.product.name, length: 20) : '' %>
```